# Can I compare a parallel and congeneric model with lavaan::anova()?

Tags: r, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I want to compare two 1-factor models: (a) a congeneric model where the loadings are optimally weighted; and (b) a parallel model where the loadings are fixed to 1 (equally weighted).

```
# (a) congeneric model (optimally weighted)
  model_1f_congeneric <- '
    total_factor =~ bdi01 + bdi02 + bdi03 + bdi04 + bdi05 + 
                    bdi06 + bdi07 + bdi08 + bdi09 + bdi10 +
                    bdi11 + bdi12 + bdi13 + bdi14 + bdi15 + 
                    bdi16 + bdi17 + bdi18 + bdi19 + bdi20
  '

  fit_1f_congeneric <- lavaan::cfa(
    model_1f_congeneric, data = df, ordered = TRUE, std.lv = TRUE
  )
  
# (b) parallel model (equally weighted)
  model_1f_parallel <- '
    total_factor =~ bdi01 + 1*bdi02 + 1*bdi03 + 1*bdi04 + 1*bdi05 + 
                    1*bdi06 + 1*bdi07 + 1*bdi08 + 1*bdi09 + 1*bdi10 +
                    1*bdi11 + 1*bdi12 + 1*bdi13 + 1*bdi14 + 1*bdi15 + 
                    1*bdi16 + 1*bdi17 + 1*bdi18 + 1*bdi19 + 1*bdi20
  '
  
  fit_1f_parallel <- lavaan::cfa(
    model_1f_parallel, data = df, ordered = TRUE, std.lv = FALSE
  )
```

I wasn't sure if these models are appropriate for a likelihood ratio test, so I checked with:

```
insight::is_nested_models(fit_1f_congeneric, fit_1f_parallel)

Some of the nested models seem to be identical
[1] TRUE
attr(,"is_nested_increasing")
[1] TRUE
attr(,"is_nested_decreasing")
[1] TRUE
```

Is this an appropriate way to compare the models?

```
lavaan::anova(fit_1f_congeneric, fit_1f_parallel)

                   Df AIC BIC  Chisq Chisq diff Df diff Pr(>Chisq)    
fit_1f_congeneric 170         263.26                                  
fit_1f_parallel   189         704.52     122.83      19  < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**Update 1**

Based on @christian-geiser's answer I went back to [the example code](https://osf.io/2gzty) from the [McNeish and Wolf paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32323277/) and noticed I had not constrained the residual variances to the same value.

I think I need to update the parallel model to the following:

```
# parallel model (equally weighted)
# https://osf.io/2gzty
  model_1f_parallel <- '
  # fix all factor loadings to 1
    total_factor =~ 1*bdi01 + 1*bdi02 + 1*bdi03 + 1*bdi04 + 1*bdi05 + 
                    1*bdi06 + 1*bdi07 + 1*bdi08 + 1*bdi09 + 1*bdi10 +
                    1*bdi11 + 1*bdi12 + 1*bdi13 + 1*bdi14 + 1*bdi15 + 
                    1*bdi16 + 1*bdi17 + 1*bdi18 + 1*bdi19 + 1*bdi20
    
  # constrain all residual variances to same value
    bdi01~~theta*bdi01
    bdi02~~theta*bdi02
    bdi03~~theta*bdi03
    bdi04~~theta*bdi04
    bdi05~~theta*bdi05
    bdi06~~theta*bdi06
    bdi07~~theta*bdi07
    bdi08~~theta*bdi08
    bdi09~~theta*bdi09
    bdi10~~theta*bdi10
    bdi11~~theta*bdi11
    bdi12~~theta*bdi12
    bdi13~~theta*bdi13
    bdi14~~theta*bdi14
    bdi15~~theta*bdi15
    bdi16~~theta*bdi16
    bdi17~~theta*bdi17
    bdi18~~theta*bdi18
    bdi19~~theta*bdi19
    bdi20~~theta*bdi20
  '
  
  fit_1f_parallel <- lavaan::cfa(
    model_1f_parallel, data = df, ordered = TRUE, std.lv = FALSE
  )
```

A new problem is that `ordered = TRUE` throws a lavaan error about the variance-covariance matrix. In the teaching example I'm using, I only have 238 observations. Hopefully treating these 0-3 items as continuous won't be too great a sin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the two models are nested and can be compared via a chi-square difference test.

Note, however, that your second model is *not* a parallel model in the sense of classical test theory. It is a (less restrictive) model of (essential) tau-equivalence. (Essentially) parallel measurement implies equal loadings *and* equal error variances (which is also nested within the congeneric model).

Comment: Thanks @christian-geiser. Very helpful. I updated my original post with an edit that I think addresses your note about equal error variances.